# Script error Unknown commit Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

Upon clicking the save button in Google Earth Engine I sometimes get a pop up window 'Script error' in bold and then below that 'Unknown commit: and then a bunch of letters/numbers'. This has happened with multiple scripts and otherwise my scripts run fine, I just can't save changes. When I reload GEE I lose the changes but can then save new changes for a little while, until I get the error again - though with a different series of letters/numbers. It seems to have gotten worse over the past month. Any ideas?

For instance, with this simple script I was able to add the print hello line and save it, the world line and save it, but it gave an error the 3rd time with the 'i' line. It seems like something with my account or ?

```
// Load the Landsat 8 scaled radiance image collection.
var landsatCollection = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1')
    .filterDate('2017-12-30', '2017-12-31');
print(landsatCollection)
// Make a cloud-free composite.
var composite = ee.Algorithms.Landsat.simpleComposite({
  collection: landsatCollection,
  asFloat: true
});
print(composite)
// Visualize the Composite
Map.addLayer(composite, {bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], max: 0.5, gamma: 2}, 'L8 Image', false);
print('hello')
print('world')
print('i')
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of a script that exhibits this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, this is rare but does happen. You need to create a new repo folder and copy your scripts into the new folder.